# Why do I get Apps in Windows 8 listed as 'Not available' sometimes?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

What affects this, and if possible, how can I prevent this? Or maybe how can I get them to be available sooner or all the time?

This pretty much happens to my game apps connected to Xbox live and a few others from time to time. It never happened before I updated the computer, but I haven't had the PC long anyway. Could it be that after updates that need a restart it does this as well (I've done two of those so far)? Anyhow, I'm frustrated, I keep clicking on a app and it not responding.

The problem fixes itself at some point, but I have not been able to stare at my PC long enough to figure out how long it takes or what happened.

Comment: Sounds like they may require a connection to some service (like Xbox Live) that takes a while to establish.

Answer (score 0):

maybe they are not available because they are updating or updates are getting installed.
Maybe the store is refreshing data or you don't have internet connection?
It's hard to tell. You need to see a pattern in it or provide more details.